# what should I use to create a web contact form?

Tags: php, forms, contacts, mailto

Hi guys this is my first question on stackoverflow.

I'm an amateur web designer designing a mostly static website..I need to create a contact form for user queries.What's the best approach for this task?

1)php's mailto function?

2)form data stored in a text file or spreadsheet?

3)database-connected(not preferred)

Any help would be really appreciated!!

Comment: This question is too vaugue, but my GUESS would be php mail function - very simple

Comment: thanks, but does it require the user to have an email client on their computer?

Comment: Well it requires the client can receive email some way (such as email client or webmail) but surely that is a requirement for running a business now days???

Comment: Please see my post, on the requirements for a user

Comment: Just to clarify - i mean website owner (as your client) nneds email, website visitor does NOT need a mail client installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a simple contact us form in php,you dont need to create any database. You have to use `mail()` function in PHP

You can refer following links to built simple contact us form :-

http://www.phpeasystep.com/phptu/8.html

http://www.freecontactform.com/email_form.php

**OR**

page1.php

```
<h2>Your Title</h2>
 
<form action="receiving.php" method="POST">
 
Name:<br><input type="text" name="name" size="40" /><br><br>
 
Email:<br><input type="text" name="email" size="40" /><br><br>
 
Phone:<br><input type="text" name="phone" size="40"><br><br>
 
Message:<br><textarea name="message" rows="3" cols="31" > </textarea><br><br>
 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
<br><br>
 
</form>
```

receiving.php

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $phone = $_POST['phone']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{
    $from_add = "contactform@yourwebsite.com"; 

    $to_add = "yourname@yourwebsite.com"; 

    $subject = "Your Subject Name";

    $message = "Name:$name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n 
Message: $message";

    $headers = "From: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_add \r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from_add\r\n";
    $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP \r\n";


    if(mail($to_add,$subject,$message,$headers)) 
    {
        $msg = "Mail sent";
    } 
}

print "<p> Thank you $name for your message,
    we will be in contact shortly. <a href=\"index.php\">Click here</a>
    to continue </p>" ;

?>
```

**NOTE :-** You cannot send mail from localhost, configure some other smtp at localhost eg : google,yahoo...

Answer (score 0):

Simply build a html-form and send the data to a php-file. Database is not needed at all, unless you want to store all messages or IP.
[A simple search will get you a lot of results.](https://www.google.com/search?q=simple%20php%20contact%20form&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

In the phpfile you have two options: Use php's [`mail()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) as is, or try [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). The latter is a bit more complecated, but ends up less as spam, it sets headers and everything for you.

Especially when you mail from multiple pointer on your website, I recommend [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/).

**In reply to one of your comments:**
All mailing happends on the server. PHP is a serverside language, **all** actions take place **on the server**, not on the users computer. For that reason, your code should always be on a server, or local with WAMP (or LAMP)

Answer (score 0):

Sample code of contact form using mail function

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    if ($name == "" || $email == "" || $message == "") {
        echo "All fields are required, please fill the form again.";
    } else {
        $from = "From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
        $subject = "Message sent using your contact form";
        mail("youremail@yoursite.com", $subject, $message, $from);
        echo "Email sent!";
    }
}
?>

<form  action="" method="POST"> 
    Your name:<br> 
    <input name="name" type="text" /><br> 
    Your email:<br> 
    <input name="email" type="text"/><br> 
    Your message:<br> 
    <textarea name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br> 
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="Send email"/> 
</form>
```

Comment: this may sound like a noob question, but do I need the site to be live (hosted) for the mail() to work, or will it work from my computer? I'm still in the early phase of development..

Comment: On a server. Again, please see the `In reply to one of your comments` in my answer :)